# Singletons Ext JS (4.2.1) and Stores

Tags: extjs, extjs-stores

How do you implement a Store to be a singleton?

In Architect my store has a property checkbox that adds the property

```
singleton: true,
```

If I add that then reload the application it fails to load (I can give more details if required about error)

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function VM5238:3
(anonymous function) VM5238:3
Ext.ClassManager.instantiate ext-all-debug.js:5485
(anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:2109
Ext.define.getStore
```

If I then remove that property it loads fine, but where I use Ext.getStore("MyStore") then the stores that are returned contain different data depending on where I'm using the store. I have a single controller where I use the class name inside the getStore method and this is used in a couple of functions inside that one controller.

Also there does not appear to be any documentation about the singleton property in the docs. If I look at Ext.data.Store there is no singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to do it the ExtJS way for handling stores and store instances...

Use the `storeId` along with the `Ext.StoreManager`. Note that each `storeId` need to be unique and as soon as you create a instance of a store it will register itself into the `Ext.StoreManager` with its `storeId`. You can get a store by calling the `lookup('storeId')` on the `Ext.StoreManager`. And yes you can do that from anywhere in your code.

For example all `Ext.Components` that mixin `Ext.util.Binable` (which are most (all) native components that bind a store) will be fine with the `storeId` string assigned to the `store` cfg property. The Binable mixin will internally lookup it from the StoreManager. If you need to do it yourself

```
//...
store: Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('storeId') || Ext.create('YourStoreClassname')
//...
```

Comment: That sounds good. what's the best way to create a store in the first instance. I was reading (on sencha site) that its best to leave id's to be generated and to use itemId's instead.
When I used the Ext.getStore it was generating the store for me.

Comment: @delp If you are using the ExtJS MVC you need to do nothing at all. The sore will be loaded and instantiated by the controller and the storeId will be the identifying name of the store class. AFAIK 'App.store.StoreName' should be 'StoreName' and 'App.store.sub.StoreName' should be 'sub.StoreName'. If you don't use MVC do it like in my example

Comment: Yes you're right. It does (if using a controller) create the store automatically and when it does it ignores the storeId you set for it and makes the storeId the same as the class name.
thanks.